# Uisearch bar ready on viewwillappear

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When my modal view appears it looks like this (ui search bar and empty table). Very typical.

[image]

I want my view when it appears to look like this

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `[self.mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder]` (Objective C) or `mySearchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` (Swift) in your `viewWillAppear` lifecycle method.